# Angular directive - asynchronous attr interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive. In it the attributes of the link function, I'm trying to get the value of attributes.user; In my view page, this custom directive is being used in the following manner:

```
<div my-directive user="{{user.name}}"></div>
```

Now user is a model object that I'm getting back from a JSON response after making a request to a certain url using the $http service. However, when I check the value of attribute.user in my directive by inserting 'debugger' in my code, I'm getting a blank for attribute.user. If I set user.name to something like "hello", I'm actually getting "hello" back. I also tried:

```
attributes.$observe('user', function(val){...})
```

but to no avail. Is this because I'm making an async request and that's why I'm getting a blank? What is going on and how do I go about resolving this? Thanks!

**Edit: Here's a snippet of my directive code**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
      $scope.user = $.parseJSON(attr.user)
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'GlobalVariables', function($scope, $rootScope, GlobalVariables) {

    $rootScope.hasSignedUp = GlobalVariables.hasSignedUp;
    $rootScope.signUpId = GlobalVariables.signUpId;

    $rootScope.$watch('hasVoted', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if(newVal === true) {
        if($rootScope.signUpId == $scope.user.id){
          $scope.text = 'Signed Up!';
        }else{
          $scope.text = 'Sign Up';
        }
      }else{
        $scope.text = 'Sign Up';
      }
     });
    }]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `scope` shouldn't be a boolean but a dictionary with the keys of the attribute you expect, change your `scope` to:

```
scope: {
    user: '=',
}
```

Also, a directory expects the scope values to be variables and not contain angular handlebars. This is the correct way to do it:

```
<div my-directive user="user"></div>
```

This should now work. See [AngularJS's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more info.

Comment: That just sets the user attribute literally to "user". I'm trying to pass in the user object itself.

Comment: no, it doesn't. it will pass the entire object into my-directive. in the template of my-drective, try to print {{user}} and you will see that the whole object exist in that scope.

Comment: Hmm...it's outputting the string "user". Not sure if this helps, but I have my scope set to true. I'm getting the user object from the controller. Also, I don't have a template for the directive. I do have a controller for it that I'm using to execute functions.

Comment: ok. missed the scope. that is your problem. see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. But still giving me back the string "user". The thing is, if I put a user object in the controller outside of an $http service call, it actually works. The problem seems to occur when I'm trying to get a user object from a JSON api response.

Comment: hmm. I see in your code that you have link defined. I don't think that is necessary if you have scope defined as I did in my answer. try to set scope like i did and remove the link. that might be it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You can define your isolated scope and binding from and two your directive like the one below

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            user:'=user'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

           //use link to subscribe and handle internal logic

           //Do something with the scope.user here

            console.log(scope.user);


        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'GlobalVariables', function ($scope, $rootScope, GlobalVariables) {

            //use this to export your directive functionality


        }]
    };
});
```

Please note that **link** function  is used to handle directive internal logic, and the **controller** function is used to export your directive functionalities.

MOre information is available here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: But that would just give me "user.name" as the value instead of the user's name. Also, I'm not necessarily trying to get the user's name. What if I want the user object passed in as the value for the user attribute?

Comment: Just bind data as normal, could you please post the source code of the your directive scope and binding operation as well ?